# How can I implement non-preemptive Priority Scheduling in Java?

Tags: java, operating-system, cpu

I want to first input the processes with their burst time and priority.
Sort the processes, burst time according to the priority.
Then calculate Waiting Time and Turn Around Time.
Finally calculate Average WT and TAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Priority {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("*** Priority Scheduling ***");

        System.out.print("Enter Number of Process: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfProcess = sc.nextInt();
        String process[] = new String[numberOfProcess];

        int p = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++) {
            process[i] = "P" + p;
            p++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(process));

        System.out.print("Enter Burst Time for " + numberOfProcess + " process: ");

        int burstTime[] = new int[numberOfProcess];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++) {
            burstTime[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(burstTime));

        System.out.print("Enter Priority for " + numberOfProcess + " process: ");

        int priority[] = new int[numberOfProcess];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++) {
            priority[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(priority));

// Sorting process & burst time by priority
int temp;
String temp2;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcess - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < numberOfProcess - 1; j++) {
            if (priority[j] > priority[j + 1]) {
                   temp = priority[j];
                    priority[j] = priority[j + 1];
                    priority[j + 1] = temp;

                    temp = burstTime[j];
                    burstTime[j] = burstTime[j + 1];
                    burstTime[j + 1] = temp;

                    temp2 = process[j];
                    process[j] = process[j + 1];
                    process[j + 1] = temp2;

                }
            }
        }

        int TAT[] = new int[numberOfProcess + 1];
        int waitingTime[] = new int[numberOfProcess + 1];

// Calculating Waiting Time & Turn Around Time
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++) {
            TAT[i] = burstTime[i] + waitingTime[i];
            waitingTime[i + 1] = TAT[i];
        }

        int totalWT = 0;
        int totalTAT = 0;
        double avgWT;
        double avgTAT;

        System.out.println("Process     BT      WT        TAT");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++) {

            System.out.println(process[i] + "          " + burstTime[i] + "       " + waitingTime[i] + "         " + (TAT[i]));
            totalTAT += (waitingTime[i] + burstTime[i]);
            totalWT += waitingTime[i];

        }

        avgWT = totalWT / (double) numberOfProcess;
        avgTAT = totalTAT / (double) numberOfProcess;

        System.out.println("\n Average Wating Time: " + avgWT);
        System.out.println(" Average Turn Around Time: " + avgTAT);

    }

}
```